# jQuery Validation Validating Wrong Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I can't get [jquery.validate.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to work correctly on a few fields. Here's the code:

```
$("#input_home_area").rules("add", {
    digits: true,
    maxlength: 3,
    minlength: 3
});

$("#input_home_prefix").rules("add", {
    digits: true,
    maxlength: 3,
    minlength: 3
});

$("#input_home_suffix").rules("add", {
    digits: true,
    maxlength: 4,
    minlength: 4
});
```

HTML:

```
<li id='' class='gfield sixth required'>
    <label class='gfield_label' for=''>Home Phone Area Code (ex: 954)</label>
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <input name='' id='input_home_area' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='6' placeholder="(ex: 954)" />
    </div>
</li>

<li id='' class='gfield sixth required'>
    <label class='gfield_label' for=''>Home Phone Prefix (ex: 555)</label>
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <input name='' id='input_home_prefix' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='6' placeholder="(ex: 555)" />
    </div>
</li>

<li id='' class='gfield sixth required'>
    <label class='gfield_label' for=''>Home Phone Suffix (ex: 1236)</label>
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <input name='' id='input_home_suffix' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='6' placeholder="(ex: 1236)" />
    </div>
</li>
```

The problem's hard to explain, but I'll try my best. When I include the bit of script that validates `#input_home_suffix`, both `#input_home_area` and `#input_home_prefix` get validated as if they where `#input_home_suffix`. So even though I've set both `#input_home_area` and `#input_home_prefix` to require 3 digits to be entered, they get validated as if 4 have to be entered. Even if I comment out the bits of script that validate `#input_home_area` and `#input_home_prefix`, they still get validated as if they're actually `#input_home_suffix`

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. Every other field on the page validates perfectly, it's just these ones that are having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Validation plugin, you have to call out inputs by the `name` attribute, not their `id`.

Comment: Are you sure? I've set it up to validate against the id of every other field on the page and it seems fine. I'll double check things.

Comment: Alright, added the exact same name, that fixed it. Thanks. That's weird.